# Finding a youtube playlist by name (YouTube API)

Tags: typescript, youtube, youtube-api, react-typescript

Is there a way to look up a playlist by name and not by URL with YouTube API?

I've been using "search", "playlistItems" and "videos".
"search" only return videos and the other 2 do not have any parameters for name.

This is what my "search" look like:

```
async function getSearchDetails(value: string, pageToken: string) {
  const { data } = await axios.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
    params: {
      part: "snippet, id",
      q: value,
      maxResults: 10,
      pageToken: pageToken,
      key: YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
    },
  });
  return data;
}
```

Comment: What about using [`type=playlist`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type)?

Comment: I completely missed that. Thank you so much!